# Using NHibernate to retrieve a set of records with a single query and composite keys

Tags: nhibernate, composite-key

I am using Nhibernate and it's mapping-by-code flavour to retrieve a set of records using a list of composite keys. I am using composite keys like this:

```
public class PersonAccountKey : IKey
{
        public virtual string PersonId { get; set; }
        public virtual string AccountNo{ get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            var t = obj as PersonKey;
            if (t == null)
                return false;
            if (PersonId == t.PersonId && AccountNo == t.AccountNo)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (PersonId).GetHashCode() + "|" + (AccountNo).GetHashCode();
        }
}
```

With a list of PersonAccountKey objects, I am trying to get NHibernate to send a single query down to database. I would imagine the query would look like this:

```
Select PersonId, AccountNo, AccountNickName 
From PersonAccount 
Where (PersonId = '11' and AccountNo = '10001111') 
or (PersonId = '22' and AccountNo = '10001150')
```

I'm not sure how to achieve this? I tried to use Criteria with composite keys, but I don't think it was meant to be used together. I am trying now Linq 2 NHibernate but am not really getting anywhere either.

Ideally, I would like a method that would take a IEnumerable of keys such as `Session.Get<T>(IEnumerable<object>)`, but this doesn't exist from my searching.

Is this possible out of the box with NHibernate?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike scalar Ids, there's no direct support to use use a list of composite keys as a query parameter. This is another example of why composite keys should be avoided.

Here's an easy workaround:

```
IEnumerable<PersonAccountKey> keys = GetKeys();
var query = session.CreateCriteria<PersonAccount>();
var keyCriterion = Restrictions.Disjunction();
foreach (var key in keys)
    keyCriterion.Add(Restrictions.Eq("id", key));
query.Add(keyCriterion);
var result = query.List<PersonAccount>();
```

Comment: Perfect. Agree that composite keys should be avoided, however what else can be done with legacy databases?

Comment: They can be refactored, for example :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on MSDN about [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx) which does what I think you want.

I don't know if NHibernate's linq supports this at all. It may refuse to do it with an exception.